# If a company is using ubuntu on its servers/dektops, does it have to pay?

Tags: server, webserver, commercial

a friend of my friend has started a small firm and given me the responsibility to erect all the IT infrastructure required? I'm basically a windows guy that too on the developer side. But recently I fell in love with Linux n dared to dream about becoming a Linux admin and play with Linux, virtualization, cloud etc.

So, first I'll be running a pilot project of creating mail/ftp/web servers required on a Linux based server. And Ubuntu is the ideal choice for a Linux beginner right?

my question is simple: if a commercial organization is using Ubuntu for it's day to day desktop and server(mail,ftp etc) uses but has technicians which can **provide support internally** then do the organization needs to pay for Ubuntu? If yes then could you please suggest a Debian based distro on the lines of CentOS.

Also can I use the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit desktop version instead of the no gui server version for the server machine(gui can be helpful for a windows guy like me)

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Ubuntu is free to use for all your needs. There is no "CentOS to Ubuntu", the same OS that you have the option to pay support for is the same OS that you can use for free.

Check out the section "The Ubuntu Promise" here:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/project

See also:

- [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Comment: so does it mean that the kernel of the desktop and server version the same?