# GUI - Installing on top of a server

Tags: gui

I installed Ubuntu-12.04-x86_64 server. I need a GUI to install mysql db. What is the simplest way? I still want to preserve my server. I don't want to make it to run as a desktop. All I need is a GUI.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could install ubuntu-desktop(just add sudo apt-get before that), and delete it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Bunsen.When I uninstall would it leave behind any sediments. OR the uninstall would be clean? Also, would it take off my server properties. I still want to boot up as server not as a desktop.

Comment: You do not need a GUI to install MySQL

Comment: jap1968 - I am novice with ubuntu. I am just starting. I am sure you might have figured it out by this time.

Comment: @Prasad I don't know what's left and what's not, I almost never check that ;)

Comment: @Prasad: if you have a specific problem with installing MySQL I think it may be better to ask it directly in a separate question. You do not need a GUI for that for sure.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your comments. Bunsen, jap1968 and Sergy.

Comment: When you install ubuntu-desktop you get a lot of packages, which will not automatically be deinstalled when you remove ubuntu-desktop again - so don't go that road!

Comment: guntbert - this was exactly my concern, when I started this chain. Again, I am back to square one. :( PLEASE HELP.

Comment: you don't need a GUI to install mysql - please follow sergey's advice and ask another question about installing mysql on a server!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Answer (score 1):

I run an Ubuntu Server myself, and various times I feel the need of a GUI. This has however proved itself to be a reflection of my own fright.

If you just take the time to learn one texteditor (such as `nano`), you will learn a lot more in the process. You can install mysql by using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, and then you edit the configuration to your needs.
What I usually do next is that I use some kind of graphical tool (such as Mysql Workbench) on my client PC to connect to the mysql server and create databases.
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html

If you however want a graphical interface on the server, you could use a webgui such as Webmin. This way, you probably save more resources than if you would install the ubuntu desktop, and when the graphical interface is not needed you can stop the service to release RAM if you are worried about resources.
http://www.webmin.com

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to run `sudo apt-get install compiz && sudo apt-get install unity` in the command line. Make sure you have an internet connection or else this will not work.

Comment: Be careful. that will pull in a great lot too - not recommended.