# What is the user interface design of Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, server, gui

Can someone explain to me the GUI and CLI of Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Out of the box: CLI only, standard Linux CLI.

Answer (score 5):

By default the Server version of Ubuntu has an interface similar to this one:

[image: server interface of Ubuntu]

So, only the [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/tags/command-line/info) is available.

Source: [Ubuntu Server “desktop” versus Ubuntu Desktop Version](http://bradkingsley.com/ubuntu-server-desktop-versus-ubuntu-desktop-version/).

> Most Ubuntu Server developers recommend not installing a GUI on a server. There are multiple reasons for not installing a GUI.
>
> Some reasons to not install a GUI include:
>
> 1. You'll have more code subject to security vulnerabilities, more
>      packages that need updating, and more server downtime.
> 2. Performance may
>      suffer because resources (memory, hard disk space, CPU, etc.) will be
>      consumed by the GUI.
> 3. It is best practice to only install needed
>      software on a production server.
> 4. The GUI may include other network
>      services that are inappropriate for a server.
>
>    - One of the goals of
>        Ubuntu Desktop Edition is to make it easier for users to use Linux.
>        When installing some desktop environments, services that you may not
>        specifically want will be installed. For example avahi-daemon, which
>        is used to help configure networking, adds another open port and may
>        introduce unwanted DNS conflicts with a .local domain.
>
> So for the most secure server it is best to
>   not install a GUI.

Source: [ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI).

See also:

- [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/53822/147044)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the user interface design of Ubuntu Server?

There's no user interface for the Ubuntu Server. Just a plain log in prompt and 6 TTY's. In fact servers do not include a User Interface beyond a prompt.

> Can someone explain to me the GUI and CLI of Ubuntu Server?

Ubuntu server is just a strip down version of the Ubuntu Desktop packages. It includes the very same set of packages. If you install any of the `-desktop` packages you will notice no differences. Ubuntu (Linux) is modular. You can plug/unplug as many part/pieces you consider. The differences between you installing the Ubuntu Server and any of the Desktop versions is that you will not have a GUI to boot, but can dedicate all those resources to your servers (daemons).

Comment: This information was so useful.