# Graphic mode in Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, gui, lxde

I have Ubuntu Server installed on virtualbox, and Ubuntu 13.10 as the host OS.

I installed the `lxde desktop` environment on the guest OS (Ubuntu Server):

```
sudo ap-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

But when I rebooted the guest it didn't run with the graphical mode.
How can I run that graphical mode ?

Comment: Why? Suggest you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui and then explain what you want to do which requires a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logout, then at login choose your GUI ('Desktop Environment')
or
run  `startx`