# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: on Ubuntu Server

Tags: xorg, virtualization

I've simply been trying to get Sublime Text 2 running on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS on a Virtual Machine but also get the same error trying to run gedit so this leads me to believe it's an environment config issue.

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I've installed gksu and tried gksu gedit with the same result.

It's really starting to hurt my head. Any suggestions/help much appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install xserver or a display server like unity,cinnamon, or gnome?

gedit or any graphical programs need a display server to be able to run.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/53822/178596. You can also use [`nano`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nano/) instead of of `gedit` if you just have a command line.

Comment: Thanks guys, some great feedback and it's making more sense now. The desktop is effectively run as a server which isn't installed as standard on the Server Install.

Thanks @Wilf, I already had Nano running but I really wanted Sublime for an article I'm following on Ruby on Rails. Thats an interesting link and some great options. The next task is to decide which display server.

The long term plan is to have Ruby on Rails running on Ubuntu Server, are there merits/benefits to any these options?