# Black/blank screen when connecting to freenx server on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, gnome, freenx

I'm attempting to log into my Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 server edition. I'm running FreeNX. I installed FreeNX more-or-less following the instructions in the [Ubuntu FreeNX documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX#Installation_Prerequisites). I modified my `/etc/nxserver/node.conf` file by setting

```
ENABLE_PASSDB_AUTHENTICATION="1"
```

and adding the line

```
COMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d'
```

which I got from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zachbrowne/3995880) that I randomly found online.

I ran the following commands to enable `passdb` authentication for my primary user (`ubuntu`)

```
sudo nxserver --adduser ubuntu
sudo nxserver --passwd ubuntu
```

I installed Ubuntu desktop

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and a slew of other desktops based on [this Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui/53577#53577):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

My current problem is that, although the login seems to be working, I'm getting a black screen in my NX client; I've tried both the NoMachine and OpenNX clients on my mac. If I mess with my client configuration, I can access a terminal over NX, but I can't start any desktops.

When I attempt to start using the default "gnome" configuration, I get a black screen. I can't figure out how to start any other shell. I'm most interested in getting some form of gnome working, but I'll take what I can get.

The primary question: why am I getting a black screen when attempting to connect to a gnome shell and what can I do about it?