# How to get in desktop mode from terminal in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04

I am new in ubuntu, Our ubuntu server is running 12.04.2 LTS
and i would like to back up the system. But the one i see in youtube 
and google is different from what i saw. after logging in username and password
still in terminal mode.from what i saw in some sites you just need to press Ctrl+Alt+f1 - f6
to switch different console.or press Ctrl+Alt+f7 to switch on desktop mode.
Most of what i saw is already in desktop mode. So i was confused?

I run lsb_release-a to find out the version running and here are the info:

No lsb modules are available
distributor id: ubuntu
description:ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
release:12.04
codename:precise

Addition to that i saw also Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it

Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Regards,

Clifford

Comment: What exactly is your question? Try to be specific. Also see: http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Desktop mode" is just a X server running on top of a virtual console. You can start it with `startx` command.

Comment: I tried to install startx here is the result"Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with--fix-missing  i am trying now the sudo apt-get update

Comment: Installation of X is described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI)

Comment: If a regular Ubuntu Server version was installed, X will not be installed along with it; the OP should install `ubuntu-desktop` first (the command is: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) and then switch to CTRL-F7, or reboot. There are numerous alternatives for ubuntu-desktop: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui) is a good starting point.

Comment: after inserting apt-get updaten and startx  my screen begin blank black screen and there is a small square with yellow background.with a writing root@ISE-ubuntu:~#

Comment: @HugoWeaving see "Full Desktop Environments" section of the link in my previous comment

Comment: thanks henkkeli and Jos...i just tried Jos comment still unpacking.after that i will try also yours.

Comment: now its in desktop mode much better. Now, i saw there is username and password. How can i create one for me. So i can start back up? Btw,is there any cons on what i did? Thanks again guys

Comment: @HugoWeaving Please ask a separate question for the username issue. As to any cons: server administrators will be used to using the command line and will therefore not usually install a GUI, which can introduce its own bugs and security issues.