# Ubuntu server GUI without internet

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, 13.04, gui

I'm new to linux but I know about the startx command which is not working. I just installed Ubuntu Server (the newest version) on a old computer. I have it working but I am unable to launch the gui. I cannot connect to the internet because I don't have a network adapter. How would I start the gui?

Comment: Why run a server with no network adapter? And who makes a computer without one? Must be an OLD computer lol, BTW try to state exact versions when asking questions as this question in 6 months, "newest version" may not be the truth.

Comment: Your option is either to get all required packages necessary for gui ( from another computer with Internet ) , transfer them to the server via usb , and install manually,  or get a usb wifi dongle , connect to the Web and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or any other gui that you may prefer

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server does not come with a GUI. Its Headless, IE: Command Line Only. You would need to run an APT-GET command which requires internet.

If you get network capabilities check out..

[Install GUI on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Answer (score 1):

Even when @FreeSoftwareServers is true, there's a way to install a GUI, download a desktop version of ubuntu, i think xubuntu (xfce) is more suitable since it's an old computer (limited resources). Burn the cd and put it on the machine.

Then you have to create a dir to mount the cd

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
```

Mount the cd on that dir, and check it ( instructions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-cdrom-in-linux/) if this doesn't work )

```
mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
du
```

That should show something like

```
.... 
/dev/sr0    952320    952320    0    100%   /mnt/cdrom
```

Then add the cd as apt source

```
sudo apt-cdrom -m --cdrom=/mnt/cdrom add
```

Then update the sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install xfce4 and slim

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 slim
```

Finally reboot the machine

```
sudo reboot
```

Note: the login didn't work the first time but from that point it worked properly.

Comment: Very nice non-internet answer!~ I'm impressed.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, i was trying to teach myself how to do it, that's why every step is properly described. Also, i don't know if i'll remember it later, so better to explain it for coming back another day.