# Ubuntu Server 16.04 installed, boots but stops video

Tags: boot, server, ssh, video

I just built myself a little pc to be used as a server, installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on it, everything went fine, rebooted, very briefly I had the choice to boot ubuntu or two other options, then it autoselected to boot ubuntu, spewed out a whole ton of logging, and then ... it just stopped.

I.e. the video output stopped. I can press keys on my keyboard what I want but it won't bring back up any video. I can see it present on the router's web gui from my main pc, but when I try to SSH into it on port 22 it immediately refuses connection...

I tried rebooting but to no avail, boots just fine until it stops the video output and then nothing. The monitor itself says: no video input.

Any help?

Comment: Can you enter concols tty: ctrl-alt-f1 ?

Comment: Had you set up openssh?

Comment: Console TTY: I cannot. My keyboard also has backlighting which is toggled through scroll lock, and that all works fine while the logging is being displayed, but after that it turns off and the system doesn't react anymore. OpenSSH: I have not set up anything and if I recall correctly I thought it was something big which was not required for simply ssh-ing to the machine itself. Therefore I believe I didn't install it either. Should I reinstall ubuntu server and install openSSH with it?

Comment: Alright, reinstalled and now included OpenSSH, and I can now ssh in. Ran a sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and blindly chose yes when asking about additional drive space, and am going to (http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui) install ubuntu-desktop. However, when I run a (sudo) ls I see no results. NONE. With and without sudo...

Comment: Alright, supposedly ubuntu-desktop is installed, I rebooted but to no avail. I also found that the directory stuff works, I just had nothing in the map or something, idunno. Brainfart.