# Install Ubuntu desktop on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server, apt, password

I have been having problems trying to install ubuntu-desktop on my VPS Ubuntu server 16.04

This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then, I added a password to the root account. I read that I had to do that to access the Ubuntu desktop. I did this:

```
sudo passwd root 
sudo passwd -u root
```

When I restart the Ubuntu server, I get the field to enter the password only. the option for username does not appear. I get this, but it says that the password I entered is incorrect. But it is correct.

[image]

Comment: May you run `xrandr -q` in terminal and update your question by the result?

Comment: When you log in on the terminal, what's the output of `id` and `getent passwd 1000`?

Comment: The suggestions and results from the [related thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui) don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct you need to use the root user.

The username is already selected, it's basically a list of usernames (actually it's the "Real Name").  Your "Real Name" just happens to be: Ubuntu.

You could check the contents of /etc/passwd to see which username has that Real Name.  And if you don't know that users password, then set it.