# Getting Ubuntu Desktop from prompt

Tags: system-installation

Okay so I have Ubuntu command prompt and I've done

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and many other things, but I still cant get Ubuntu GUI (on my desktop). Can someone help me?

Comment: Refer this link [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Answer (score 2):

Having installed the necessary components, issue

`sudo service lightdm start`

to start your graphical desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that you have a ubuntu command prompt? Are you running a server version of ubuntu? Please mention the exact commands that you have run. Your question suggests that you are using a desktop version but how did you not have the GUI in the first place? Please elaborate.

Comment: yes its the server version and ive used the commands mentioned in the comment

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop        sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: Ok, the first thing to do would be to reboot the server and check. If that doesn't work its possible that X server is not running. Type "startx" on command prompt and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Oi i did all that and it keeps saying error files not found and stuff

Comment: i tried rebooting and startx and sudo service lightdm start didnt work

Comment: also saying something about bus not available and cant find/run bus files

Comment: Please describe the errors accurately, including after trying to run what commands you get those errors.