# I cannot type "|" in Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard

I also cannot press "\" (this is not important right now)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Erm, your screenshots don't show anything, and sometimes Ubuntu can take some time to boot, especially if you're installed the GUI version in a VBox VM without a ton of video RAM and vCPU/vRAM settings.  This is especially the case in VBox, which isn't as kind with system memory and resources as VMware (which is also not too nice either way).  Are you working on a Server or GUI installation of Ubuntu inside that VM?

Comment: @thomas what screenshot do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

For console-only instances, e.g. servers, install the *console-data* package.

```
sudo apt-get install console-data
```

Set up the input language.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

When the configuration dialog is displayed, choose to select a keymap from the "arch list". The most common keyboard layout is "qwerty" (look at the first row of letters in your keyboard), so choose this unless you have something different.

Next, select a keyboard layout. The English language keyboard contains the | and \ characters that are currently missing.

Press OK and you're done. Reboot the guest OS  with `sudo reboot` to use your new keyboard layout.

Comment: Sorry I do exactly what you say (I choose America keyboard) but it still does not solve the problem. I do not see Text Entry option

Comment: That's not surprising if you have a server and no GUI is installed, because the Text Entry option in System Settings is for GUI only.

Comment: I try to download GUI using https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui but now my Ubuntu cannot bootup. I am currently trying to fix it

Comment: After spending hours looking for solution, I try to just make the new instance. This time with bigger RAM and storage. Somehow the keyboard now can type "|" already. Wonder why?

Comment: My out of the clear blue sky guess is that you could have also done the same thing by adding more Video Memory in VirtualBox -> select a guest OS (web-server) ->  *Settings* -> *Display* -> *Screen* tab. The default Video Memory size is 16MB. You can increase Video Memory to 128MB in VirtualBox settings by moving the slider, and increase it to 256MB from the terminal with the command: `VBoxManage modifyvm "web-server" --vram 256`