# I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 on Virtualbox and logged in but nothing happens. What could be the reason and how can I resolve this?

Tags: boot, virtualbox

This image shows how (part of) my screen looks like. There is just ~$ and I don't know what to do now.

[image]

Before that I had a line saying something like: Proxy ' ' is invalid
This however didn't show up anymore. During the installation there was once something with proxy server but I think I left it blank.

Comment: It apparently is the server edition that comes without a GUI. Nothing wrong here. You may have accidentally downloaded the wrong ISO.

Comment: So should I just do the installation again with a different ISO file? And by the way I added some information to the question: Before that I had a line saying something like: Proxy ' ' is invalid        This however didn't show up anymore. During the installation there was once something with proxy server but I think I left it blank.

Comment: just download the desktop version ISO and try or install it.

Comment: Yeah, downloading and installing the desktop version would be the recommended way. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: yeah that will be better.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I don't know why I downloaded the server version and not the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

That is ubuntu "server". It is ubuntu 16.04 simply without all the nonsence packages.

If you do not want to restart your machine you can install the ubuntu-desktop package to get the GUI up and running. See here : [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)