# Ubuntu server - setup up GUI environment

Tags: server

I am confused, I found these 2 questions from Stack:

[How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

[How To Set Up GUI On Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server)

I am using AWS, and I'm connecting to the EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance using PuTTY with SSH (from Windows 10). Now I am not sure which guide of the 2 above is suitable for me: Because I am already connected to the Ubuntu server remotely, so can I just install ubuntu-desktop and somehow launch it via PuTTY? Or I have to use VNC? I tried to simply do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, but nothing showed up later.

Comment: VNC is probably the most straightforward protocol for you to use. You need `ubuntu-desktop` for that anyway (or large parts of it, such as X).

Comment: I'd recommend a lighter desktop such as LXDE or XFCE for use over VNC

Comment: amazon workspaces: https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/ is an option.