# issue with pgadmin installing in ubuntu18 server

Tags: postgresql

I have ubuntu 18 server installed & i want to make it postgres sql server for my own practice, Installed postgres but unable to get pgadmin tool. Any suggestion guys??????

Tried many times using "apt-get install pgadmin"

no success.

Answer (score 0):

The actual package name is [pgadmin3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pgadmin3), which resides in universe repository, so

- make sure you have [universe repository enabled](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/295286)
- run `sudo bash -c 'apt-get udpate && apt-get install pgadmin3'` command

Please also note that it's a graphical software. You said you've installed Ubuntu server edition, so if you don't have GUI installed, you might [have to install it](https://askubuntu.com/q/53822/295286).

Alternatively, [download a .deb archive](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pgadmin3) and [install manually.](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/295286)