# How to install nautilus in Ubuntu

Tags: nautilus

I removed nautilus from my laptop and I had lost everything. When iam trying to install nautilus it requires some dependencies.
How can I get it now??
I used `sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus` to remove nautilus

Comment: Also include the command(s) you used to remove nautilus in the first place. Perhaps you removed more than you intended.

Comment: On recent ubuntu, `sudo apt remove nautilus` will remove ubuntu-desktop as well.

Comment: It might seem counter-intuitive to follow [this duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui), but you've not only lost nautilus, but your entire desktop system.  following the instructions on how to  install a GUI will solve your problem. cc @karel

Comment: @karel I have just purged `nautilus` on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 18.10 VMs - it removed `nautilus`, `nautilus-share` and `ubuntu-desktop`, but system is still usable. Running `apt autoremove` removes only old kernels, either. So the main problem of this question is lack or details.

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu desktop system package (*ubuntu-desktop*) depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu desktop system. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop  
sudo reboot
```

In order to preview what `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` installs without installing anything run `apt show ubuntu-desktop`

In order to simulate what `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` installs without installing anything run `apt install ubuntu-desktop --simulate`

Comment: I somehow managed to remove `files` or `nautilus`, whatever the default file manager on Ubuntu 23.04 and thankfully `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` resolved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a package has dependencies that cannot be satisfied you can use `aptitude` to resolve them:

```
sudo aptitude install nautilus
```

This will give you choices on which packages to keep or remove such that nautilus can be installed. There can be many different ways to resolve dependencies and you don't have to accept the first choices given. Keep answering the prompts about which packages you want to keep or remove until the dependencies are resolved.

Comment: That's likely because that package is no longer needed and would be removed by `apt autoremove` anyhow.

Comment: That's because I updated the kernel today, but I haven't run `sudo apt autoremove` after updating the kernel yet.