# Ubuntu-desktop installed on Ubuntu Server. login screen goes nowhere

Tags: server, unity, login

Followed these instructions [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui) on a new install of Ubuntu Server.

Partial success. I get the purple Ubuntu login screen, my user account is selected, and I can enter my password. However, it just returns me back to the very same screen with no errors or warnings.

I know the password is good because I use it with that same account to ssh in.

What have I missed?

Comment: Check /var/crash and /var/log/syslog for the error messages. You are describing the classic symptoms of a *desktop crash*.

Comment: Thanks! /var/crash is empty.

Comment: /var/syslog showed me far too much, but I picked through grep on error and got 
`Mar 29 15:22:06 imac org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2344]: libinput error: client bug: timer event6 debounce: offset negative (-6ms)`


`Mar 29 15:22:06 imac org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2344]: libinput error: client bug: timer event6 debounce short: offset negative (-19ms)`

Those seemed like the only things I saw that might be important.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release details, and as you mentioned server; have you met the hardware requirements (video card) for Ubuntu Desktop in your release?  (many servers do not meet minimum requirements of GNOME for example, but will run lighter desktops)   *Note: I know this can be an issue, but I am unsure of effect if minimum desktop requirements aren't met*  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Apologies. It's  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-91-generic x86_64), running on a 2009 iMac with, for its day, a comparatively beefy GPU.