# Install Ubuntu Desktop from 1Gb Usb Stick

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu Desktop, however, I only have a 1GB Usb Stick which is not large enough. Is it possible to install Ubuntu Desktop for example from the server image while downloading the additional packages from the internet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ubuntu Minimal: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

> The minimal iso image will download packages from online archives at installation time instead of providing them on the install media itself. Downloading packages at install time reduces the size of the iso image to approximately ~40MB depending on architecture

But it won't work in UEFI mode, if you need that you can use the server image:

> While the minimal iso image is handy, it isn't useful for installing on UEFI-based systems that you want to run in UEFI mode. The mini iso lacks the proper files for booting the computer in UEFI mode. Thus, the computer will boot in BIOS compatibility mode, and the installation will be in BIOS mode.
>
> You can use an Ubuntu Server amd64 iso file (64-bit) for 'mini installations' in UEFI mode.
>
> See this link: [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, install the server distribution  and then you download the GUI. 
This might be helpful: [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried this, however, the screen stays black after reboot. can only login in into asci screen

Comment: Need to correct myself it seems to be the standard login screen background color and I even see the mouse cursor. However, I don't see a login

Comment: So you have set the default target to be `graphical` and still no result

Comment: How do I set the default target to graphical? I assume this has been done automatically.
I see a graphical screen in the dark purplish color with a mouse cursor but no login line

Comment: Yes it`s probably activated automatically if you are seeing the purple background but try `systemctl set-default graphical.target ` and reboot

Comment: Didn't change anything. I added an Image of the screen to the post

Comment: Well can you boot in multiuser mode and read the /var/log/gdm.log.old and see if there is something suspicious

Comment: I just did this on my old laptop. More because I want fallback/gnome-panel. `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`
creates symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target  But just installing gnome-panel did not fully add all the gui bits. Normally I install full Ubuntu & add gnome-panel, but laptop only has 1.5GB of RAM, so full desktop will not install. Full desktop
 `sudo tasksel install desktop gnome-desktop` I am installing the extra bits I need to get it working without full desktop.