# Need help on my Ubuntu server installation

Tags: server, software-installation, 20.04, gui

Needed help, I've tried commands but still not continuing to the desktop. badly needed help.

[image: Ubuntu Server 20.04]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Comment: This did not load the image for some seonds, I was a little confused, at first.

Comment: This question should be closed/put on hold until the original poster actually asks a question, right now people are just guessing what the question is.

Comment: have you tried `startx` ?

Answer (score 10):

If you installed Ubuntu Server, the command prompt you show in the photo is perfectly normal. A graphical desktop environment is not installed by default.

Either you can reinstall Ubuntu (the normal desktop version) and setup your server applications from there, or you can install a graphical desktop on top of your existing installation as follows (I'll just give you an example for Gnome, if you want anything else the internet is full of help :) ).

Run the following commands from the command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

You should now be shown a graphical login screen!

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the Ubuntu server version which does not include a desktop by default. So all operations you want to perform would be via a CLI (command-line interface) which is what the primary focus of a server type environment is.

## Easiest thing you can do if you don't have CLI expertise

Download a Ubuntu Desktop version from Ubuntu website
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop and reinstall it.

## Alternate method through shell prompt

Start by updating the repositories and package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Next, install the tasksel manager utility:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Choose a display manager. Many options are available from lightweight to high function desktop environment. Below is an example of Xubuntu - a moderately lightweight GUI for ubuntu

E.g. Install Xubuntu by entering the following:

```
sudo tasksel install xubuntu-core
```

Launch your desktop by

```
sudo service display_manager start
```

If you need to stop the desktop and return to the terminal shell

```
sudo service display_manager start
```