# Is there an Ubuntu Server version with GUI available to download?

Tags: server, system-installation, gui

Is there a server version that has the GUI included in the ISO?

If there is, can you please give me the URL for the download?

Hopefully it is one of the latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

No, not included in the iso. However, you can install using the server iso and then use `tasksel` to install the desktop.

First, install the server from the iso.

Next, boot up and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo tasksel
```

If you get a "command not found" error, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

Then, select the ubuntu desktop from the list. DO NOT select any of the "live" versions.

Use the arrow keys to navigate, the <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to select, and the <kbd>tab</kbd> key and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to select OK when you are done.

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.

Reboot after installation and you will have a working desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ubuntu Server ISO with a gui.

Ubuntu has many ISOs which contain desktops; they're called Ubuntu Desktop or [*flavors* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) each with the default desktop (apps & sometimes toolkits/libs) replaced with other choices.

Servers are usually serving other machines, where a GUI will just *waste* resources thus reducing efficiency. As efficiency is a goal, GUI is not included.

Many Ubuntu ISOs are available, the difference being the default packages included; so grab the closest to your need & add the packages required (ie. `apt install`, `snap install` etc though if you want a package manager (eg. `aptitude`) to automate some of this choices are always available).

**No special tool is required**; as standard package commands are all that's needed to add a desktop.

You can look at the manifest etc (*available where you download an ISO*) to see the packages included; it's an easy way to compare with other ISOs as there are many ISO choices available, should you want to find an ISO that contains most of what you need... eg. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/21.10/release/ubuntu-21.10-live-server-arm64.manifest (*also note some install options may result in different packages actually installed*)

Comment: Thanks guiverc, I will try this to see if it does the job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick a GUI desktop environment upon a "server" installation, you can do so, quite simply, using these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

However, for a server in a production environment it doesn't make all that much sense.

For more information see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/53577/348964) to [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/53822/348964), which is (essentially) the same question as you are asking.