# Ububtu Server 22.04 LTS, tasksel not displaying option for Jammy Jellyfish GUI

Tags: server, gnome, tasksel

I wish to have Jammy Jellyfish GUI available for use on a Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS.

On an Oracle VM(v6.1.14) I have successfully installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (.iso downloaded from https://ubuntu.com/download/server and Option 2 was selected).  The installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS went without a hitch.

Next, from the CLI, I installed `tasksel` and when I run `tasksel --list-task` I get the following image which does not have the Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish GUI listed. Debian is the default GUI and Debian is also installed when I choose GNOME or GNOME Flashback

This is a list of the options available.  Jammy Jellyfish does not seem to be an available option.
[tasksel --list-task options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHkSa.png)

Any ideas, anyone, please,
Tommy.

Comment: You're confusing a release codename - *jammy jellyfish* AKA Ubuntu 22.04 - with the desktop environments.

Comment: "tasksel" got discontinued a long time ago iirc.  We nowadays use a `^` to install a task (`sudo apt install {task}^`  will have the text underneath it show it is going to install a task. " Jammy Jellyfish does not seem to be an available option. " it never will. You install a task in an operating system, not an operating system. So the task can be budgie-desktop and when on Jammy will install Jammy's version

Comment: Good morning Karel.  Yes, you are correct this answers the question.  I had discovered this myself on Friday afternoon after a long search.  I did not find your informative suggested answer.  The `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop` is an excellent addition, one that I will be trying.

Comment: @Karel.  I tested `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` on VMs on 3 different machines last Friday,  all successful.   Question that arises now is why in Ubuntu Server 22.04 Ubuntu Desktop is not the default GUI?  Why was this changed from 20.04?

Comment: It might have something to do with Wayland vs. Xorg. In Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME desktop environment the default session for most systems that don’t have an Nvidia graphics card is now Wayland.

Comment: @Karel, Please forgive my limited knowledge.  Does this mean then even though an Nvidia graphics card is installed on a host machine the VM "graphics card" may be recognized as something else?  Hence the changed default GUI.  If this is so. then I think that Ubuntu and Linux are really very clever systems.   Though I do like Mint GUI also.  :-)

Comment: It doesn't mean that. Wayland doesn't work with the proprietary graphics drivers for Nvidia graphics cards, so users of these drivers in Ubuntu have to use Xorg instead of Wayland. Otherwise they may get boot problems which is not wanted for users of Ubuntu Server 22.04.

Comment: Thanks Karel.  I appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: FYI:  another very useful answer,  lots of information.  [How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)