# How do I access Ubuntu via Remote Desktop?

Tags: server, ssh

I followed the link below and installed the GUI on Ubuntu Server 20.04

1. I've Installed XRPD (below) but I'm unable to access Ubuntu remotely.  When I access the VPS's url I get connection timeout.
2. After installing Ubuntu GUI (below) I lost access to Cyberpanel (an alternative to cPanel)- I checked the port number in /usr/local/lscp/conf/bind.conf and is correct, but after the GUI update I get timeout error when I try to access CyberPanel. CyberPanel port is enabled in UFW

Many thanks

[How do you run Ubuntu Server with a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui)

Installing XRPD:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/

CyberPanel : https://cyberpanel.net

Comment: Your question isn't clear, I don't understand whether you want steps on how to access Ubuntu over SSH, or Remote Desk, or the question is unrelated entirely.

Comment: My question is 1. about accessing Ubuntu via Remote Desktop, and 2. Why I lost access to CyberPanel after the Ubuntu GUI update? Thanks

Comment: Question 1: Check that your VPS is actually on and running. Try a ping using your server's domain name, and then try again using your server's IP address. Show us actual input and output of both tries.

Comment: Thanks for your support, please have the result [here](https://www.levaweb.com/tmp/ss_0101_205504.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*Update*

Point #1: It turns out that Win 10 Home do not have Remote Desktop capabilities, so I'll need to upgrade to Win 10 Pro or Enterprise in order to connect with Ubuntu remotely.

Point #2 is resolved.
I found out that the GUI Update deleted the *firewalld* port used by Cyberpanel.

I added it back as below:

```
> sudo systemctl start firewalld

> sudo systemctl enable firewalld

> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=1234/tcp
```

Where 1234 is the port used to access Cyberpanel.

Comment: You can install vncserver on any windows machine regardless of whether it is home or not... No need to upgrade the license, honestly... Unless there is something else you need from the pro license.